# Calcular los ultimos 5 digitos de la serie de fibonacci para el numero 1 millon

Tags: java, fibonacci

estoy realizando ese ejercicio pero no consigo llegar al resultado correcto. Por el momento este es el codigo que he podido realizar. (Es en java)

```
int n = 1000000;
        int[] fib = new int[n];
        fib[0] = 0;
        fib[1] = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
        }
        System.out.println("Los ultimos 5 digitos de la serie de fibonacci para el numero 1 millon son: " + fib[n - 1] % 100000);
```

Eso me da como resultado -62526, por lo que entiendo que es incorrecto.

Agradezco su tiempo y ayuda.

Comment: Si revisas como incrementan de rápido los número de fibonacci te darás cuenta que para 1_000_000, el valor es tan alto que no se puede guardar en un `int` o un `long`, el número negativo que obtienes es a causa del desbordamiento. Podrías usar BigInt https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: Gracias! Lo pude solucionar con bigInt

Comment: Nahuel, ponlo entonces como respuesta, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer). En todo caso, pídele a @Lobos que lo redacte como respuesta, para poder aceptarla :) Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.